# Interpreting/decoding a byte stream in the payload of network packages

Tags: python, byte, decode, encode, scapy

I receive bytestreams over a network in the payloads of TCP packets such as the following :
`b'\x00\x00\x00\n\xef\xbb\xbf4_test\x00'`

What I am expecting in the payload is some numerical values and strings . However I have no idea at all how to interpret these byte streams . Is this `UTF-8` or `ASCII` ?Or there is no decoding required? What is the meaning of `'\n'` in relation to adjacent bytes?

I need some clue and directions.

For those who are familiar with Scapy,
the value is accessed and printed by

```
print(packet[Raw])
```

Comment: In python the contents of a byte string are displayed as utf-8 characters where a mapping exists, but any others are displayed as the raw byte value. This is why you can see the \n and test_4, as the bytes mean something  - have a read of this: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Python_Concepts/Bytes_objects_and_Bytearrays#bytes_object_displayed

Answer (score 0):

If byte has code which can be converted to ASCII char then it displays it as char - this way you can easly see if there is some readable text.

But it doesn't care if there are `UTF-8` codes (or other codes like `latin1`, `cp1250`) because it doesn't have information which encoding was used to create strings.

If you want all as hex values then you can use `.hex(separator)`

```
a = b'\x00\x00\x00\n\xef\xbb\xbf4_test\x00'

print(a.hex())

print(a.hex(' '))

print(a.hex(':').upper())
```

Result:

```
0000000aefbbbf345f7465737400

00 00 00 0a ef bb bf 34 5f 74 65 73 74 00

00:00:00:0A:EF:BB:BF:34:5F:74:65:73:74:00
```

---

In bytes `\n` means code `0a` (for [new line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)) and `\r` means `0d` (for [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return))